# CXF java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Tags: web-services, cxf, soap-client, connection-timeout

I am getting a connection timed out when I try to invoke from a WS client a method from a CXF Web service I have deployed. Both are using custom interceptors, and the service is overloaded due to multiple invocations.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:12005/myservice/repository?wsdl: Connection timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1338)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1322)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:622)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 36 more
```

I tried multiple solutions to disabled the timeout or to increase it but all failed.

First, I tried to create a CXF configuration file like the following:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
           http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
        <http-conf:client CacheControl="no-cache"
            ConnectionTimeout="0" ReceiveTimeout="0" AllowChunking="false" />
    </http-conf:conduit>
</beans>
```

Then, I forced my application to load it by using the Java system property `-Dcxf.config.file=/home/test/resources/cxf.xml`

In the logs I can see that the configuration is read and thus *probably applied*

> INFO: Loaded configuration file /home/test/resources/cxf.xml.

Unfortunately the connection timed out still occurs.

The second solution I tried consists of setting the policy programmatically on all the clients by using the following piece of code:

```java
public static void setHTTPPolicy(Client client) {
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(0);
    httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(0);
    httpClientPolicy.setAsyncExecuteTimeout(0);

    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
}
```

but again the connection timeout occurs.

Do I miss something? Is there some other timeouts to configure? any help is welcome.

Comment: A connection timeout is usually a symptom of another problem, and not a cause by itself. Are you saying that for some invocations of the service, the connection *doesn't* timeout?

Comment: Yes, some invocations are working well. My scenario consists of transferring big attachments, thus it explains the timeout. The issue I have is really with the configuration of the timeouts on the client and the server side.

Comment: Ah. Then I'd recommend thread pooling. Find my answer below shortly.

Answer (score 1):

CXF allows you to configure threadpooling for your webservice endpoint. This way, you can cater for timeouts occurring as a result of scarce request processing resources. Below is a sample config using the `<jaxws:endpoint/>` option in cxf:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="serviceBean"  implementor="#referenceToServiceBeanDefinition" address="/MyEndpointAddress">
        <jaxws:executor>
             <bean id="threadPool" class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor">  
                 <!-- Minimum number of waiting threads in the pool -->
                 <constructor-arg index="0" value="2"/>
                 <!-- Maximum number of working threads in the pool -->
                 <constructor-arg index="1" value="5"/>
                 <!-- Maximum wait time for a thread to complete execution -->
                 <constructor-arg index="2" value="400000"/>
                 <!-- Unit of wait time -->
                 <constructor-arg index="3" value="#{T(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).MILLISECONDS}"/>
                 <!-- Storage data structure for waiting thread tasks -->
                 <constructor-arg index="4" ref="taskQueue"/>
             </bean>
         </jaxws:executor>
    </jaxws:endpoint>

    <!-- Basic data structure to temporarily hold waiting tasks-->
    <bean id="taskQueue" class="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue"/>
```